# Filter SQL results by date using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

I am getting data from an SQL table via PHP to populate an HTML table. This is how I do it:

```
<table class="posts">
        <?php 
        $respost = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_author=$uid LIMIT 16 ");
        $row_count=0;
        $col_count=0;
        while($rowpost = mysqli_fetch_array($respost)) {
            if($row_count%4==0){
                echo "<tr>";
                $col_count=1;
            }?>
            <td>
            <?php
            $imageid = $rowpost['thumbnail_link'];
            <img src="<?php echo $imageid; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" height="220px" height="220px">
            <h3><?php echo $rowpost['post_title']; ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo (substr($rowpost['post_excerpt'],0,30)); ?></h4>
            <h5><?php echo $rowpost['post_date']; ?></a></h5>
            </td>
            <?php 
            if($col_count%4==0){
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            $row_count++; 
            $col_count++; 
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Now what I want to do is, to set a filter to this. I want to add two date selectors and when the user clicks the Filter button, the table should be populated only with posts posted within the two given dates.

I thought of using a form for the date selector:

```
<form name="filter" method="POST" action="team_as.php">
    SHOW POSTS FROM:
        <input type="date" name="sdate">
        <input type="date" name="edate">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

PHP to handle that data:

```
$edate = $_POST['edate'];
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$filter = "AND $date < post_date > $edate";
```

I was wondering if there is a way to include this `$filter` in the `$respost` mysql query like this:

```
$respost = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_author=$uid $filter LIMIT 16 ");
```

Also note that the `$uid` is taken from a previous page using the `$_GET[]` method. So the this page's link looks like `www.mysite.com/page?uid=66`. So wondering if using POST and form to filter will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if you do POST, its better to add `uid` as hidden field in youf second form in order to keep it. Also use BETWEEN in your filter, so the code should look like this:

```
    <form name="filter" method="POST" action="team_as.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
        SHOW POSTS FROM:
        <input type="date" name="sdate">
        <input type="date" name="edate">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $edate = $_POST['edate'];
        $sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
        $filter = "AND DATE(post_date) BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate'";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_author=$uid $filter LIMIT 16 ";
        $respost = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_author=$uid LIMIT 16 ";
        $respost = mysqli_query($link, $query);            
    }
    ?>
```

Update: By the way, there is a small form 'hack' which allows you to use both GET and POST vars (insead of using hidden field), but is not a good practice at all, so I not recommend it:

```
<form name="filter" method="POST" action="team_as.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>">
```

when you submit this form, you will have both GET and POST arrays assigned, i.e. you will have `uid` as GET var, all others will be into POST array.

Comment: I added this and submitted, the page refreshes without `?uid=66` at the end of the link and still shows the same results as before. Didn't filter. The uid is important because the page should show the posts done by that user only. Also FYI, the `post_date` is in this format: `2014-03-11 12:25:41`

Comment: Yes, because you are doing POST. However `uid` variable will be there so you can use it as usual. The easiest way to check this is to do `echo $respost;` in order to check entire query how it looks. Regarding date format, i have updated my code in `$filter` part.

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Comment: @YohanBlake, i've put small update with how to use GET and POST together, but again, this is not good practice.

Comment: @Chay22, how your comment is related with this topic?

Comment: @mitkosoft, yes the GET and link thing works fine now, but it still doesn't filter

Comment: @mitkosoft I wrote before seeing your updated code, since action form didnt point out to page with `$_GET` before

Comment: @YohanBlake, just do `echo` of the built query and see how it looks.

Comment: @mitkosoft `AND DATE(post_date) BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-12-01' ` that's the result

Comment: nope, `$respost` is the result. see latest update above with `$query` var. echo this query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_author=59 AND DATE(post_date) BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-12-01' LIMIT 16 ` . That's what I get. Not filtering yet. Has it got to do with the date format? As I mentioned before, the date in the db has this format `2014-03-11 12:25:41`

Comment: mate! works. I had to take off the `$respost` that was defined within the table

Comment: great! finally. :) the query is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Complete Code With Date Filter

```
<div class="table-responsive m-t-10">
                                    <form class="form-group" method='post' style="margin-bottom: -5px;">
                          Start Date <input class="form-group" type='date' class='dateFilter' name='dateFrom' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['dateFrom'])) echo $_POST['dateFrom']; ?>'>

                          End Date <input class="form-group" type='date' class='dateFilter' name='dateTo' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['dateTo'])) echo $_POST['dateTo']; ?>'>

                          <input type='submit' name='but_search' value='Search'>
                        </form> 
                                       <table id="myTable"  class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
                                            <!--<table class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">-->
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                  <th>Date</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Name</th>
                                                  <th>Company</th>
                                                  <th>Userid</th>
                                                  <th>Address</th>
                                                  <th>Area</th>
                                                  <th>Contact</th>
                                                  <th style="display:none">Location</th>
                                                  <th style="display:none">Product Id</th>
                                                  <th>Software Id</th>
                                                  <th>Product Key</th>
                                                  <th>Validity</th>
                                                  <th>Unpaid Amount</th>
                                                  <th>Action</th>
                                                  <th>Enab/Disa</th>
                                                  <th >Delete</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tfoot style="display:none">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Date</th>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Userid</th>
                                                    <th>Address</th>
                                                    <th>Area</th>
                                                    <th>Contact</th>
                                                    <th>Software</th>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                    <th>Product Id</th>
                                                    <th>Validity</th>
                                                    <th>Unpaid Amount</th>
                                                    <th>Action</th>
                                                    <th>Enab/Disa</th>
                                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <?php
                                          $ses = $_SESSION["userid"];
                                          $result = mysqli_query($con, "select id from cmp_user where userid='$ses'");
                                          while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                              $uid =$res['id'];
                                          }
                                          ?>

                                                    <?php
                                                     $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']));
                                                     $dateTo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateTo']));
                                                    $result= mysqli_query($con, "select * from cmp_customer");
                                                    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                        if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res['date']))>$dateFrom && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($res['date'])) < $dateTo) {
                                                            ?>
                                                        echo "<tr>"; ?>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["date"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["c_name"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["company"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["userid"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo substr($res["address"], 0, 15); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo substr($res["zipcode"], 0, 15); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["contact"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td style="display:none"><?php echo $res["location"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td style="display:none"><?php echo substr($res["productid"], 0, 15); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo substr($res["softwareid"], 0, 15); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo substr($res["productkey"], 0, 15); ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["Validity"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $res["unpaidamt"]; ?></td>
                                                    <td><A class='btn btn-outline-success btn-sm' href="update_customer.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">Edit</A></td>
                                                    <?php if ($res["status"] == 1) {
                                                                ?>
                                                         <td> <a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want Disable this Customer ?')" href="customerstatusdisable.php?userid=<?php echo $res['userid']; ?>">Enable
                                                        </a></td>
                                                        <?php
                                                            } else { ?>
                                                     <td><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want Enable this Customer ?')" href="customerstatus.php?userid=<?php echo $res['userid']; ?>">Disable
                                                        </a></td>

                                                         <?php } ?>
                                                    <td><a class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want delete this Customer ?')" href="delete_customer.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">Delete
                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete" ></i></a></td>
                                                  <?php echo "</tr>";
                                                        }
                                                    } ?>


                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add your url value in hidden field like this

```
if(isset($_GET['uid']))
{
  $uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);
}  
<form name="filter" method="POST" action="team_as.php">
SHOW POSTS FROM:
    <input type="date" name="sdate">
    <input type="date" name="edate">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

You must add a variable for to output query

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  $uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['uid']);
  $edate = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['edate']);
  $sdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sdate']);
 }
 $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_author='$uid'";
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   $sql.= " AND $date < post_date > $edate";
  }  
 $respost = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

I think it solves your problem